# GAE No route to host error

Tags: google-app-engine

When deploying my GAE app I get the following error:

```
ERROR appcfg.py:2161 An error occurred processing file '': <urlopen error [Errno 65] No route to host>. Aborting.
```

When I try to rollback the last update I get the same error. What steps can I take to debug this?

Comment: This is a network error. First thing to check,  do you have to have a proxy configured when access the production appengine console with your browser ?  If so you need to configure appcfg to use a proxy as well.

Comment: I don't need a proxy to access the prod console. It seems to have come right again, so I suppose I'll put this one down to "internet static" and hope the network stays stable.